# Vue + Asp.Net MVC - Using vue mustache in cshtml attributes

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

As we know from Vue's documentation we can use vue mustaches to acces properties also inside of html element's attributes

But for some reason I can't make this work in .net's `.cshtml`pages

heres simple example (for ui I am using Element-UI library):

```
<el-table :data="tableData"
      row-key="Id">
    <el-table-column prop="Price"
                     label="Standard">
        <template slot-scope="props">
            <span v-if="edit == false">{{ props.row.Price }}</span> @*this is working*@
            <div v-if="edit == true">
                <input id="price-{{ props.row.Id }}" type="text" v-model="props.row.Price">@*v-model works but id not*@
            </div>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Output in source code says that Id of input element is `price-{{ props.row.Id }}`, but should be for example `price-1`

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: I'd be curious to see what your markup looks like if you temporarily disabled Vue. Is the Razor templating engine stripping out your syntax that Vue needs?

Comment: I added comments in quesiton's code

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to bind row.id to textbox id attribute. You should do it like below.

`<input v-bind:id="props.row.Id" customeAttr="price" type="text" v-model="props.row.Price">`

OR you can change your model data to have a get property which can return custom string like 'price-' + id.

```
{
  id: 1,
  price: 10,
  get customId() {        
    return 'price-' + this.id;
  }      
}
```

[Detailed Example](https://codepen.io/nitin1982/pen/RwNjwvK)

Comment: it's working, but what if i'll have lots of properties like this? I need to create many methods then

Comment: Why do you need such custom Id, why not use just id? If you can elaborate more, I may think some other solution. e.g. if you want to see if this input control for field 'Price', you can add one more attribute. e.g. I did customAttr="price".